# holoviews/bokeh gridline issue

Tags: python, bokeh, heatmap, holoviews

I am attempting to make a heat map with holoviews (currently using the bokeh backend). I have a data frame ('dep_df') with 3 columns: X, Y, type. X and Y are the dimension labels, and type is a categorical variables b/n 0 and n (where n is an integer). Here's my code:

```
dep_hm = hv.HeatMap(dep_df[["X", "Y", "type"]], label="DEP population")
TOOLS = ['hover']
colors = palettes.d3['Category20b'][5]

%%opts HeatMap [width=300, height=300, xaxis=None, yaxis=None, show_grid=True]
grid_style = {'grid_line_color': 'white', 'grid_line_width': 1.5}
dep_hm.options(cmap=ListedColormap(colors), gridstyle=grid_style, tools=TOOLS, invert_axes=True)
```

The plot looks correct in Jupiter notebook except that the ygrid lines don't show (only xgrid), and its showing all tools instead of just 'hover' as I specified. Even with the grid lines that do show, there's always a missing gridline exactly in the middle (have had that issue even in straight bokeh implementations of this heatmap.

Another issue is that I've tried saving the file to HTML using both Bokeh.io and renderer.save() and in both cases, all formatting options are not executed (like not showing the axes, inverting the axes, and not showing full toolbar options). it seems to just save the plot with default options. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

renderer.save() doesn't read the notebook magic i.e. `%%opts HeatMap [width=300, height=300, xaxis=None, yaxis=None, show_grid=True]`

You have to use `your_variable.options(width=300, height=300, xaxis=None, yaxis=None, show_grid=True)` to make it stick. See http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Customizing_Plots.html `Simplified format`

Not sure about your other issue though.